# Infinite connected $T_2$-space with fixed-cardinality fibers

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

What is an example of a connected $T_2$-space $(X,\tau)$ with $X$ infinite and the following property?

> If $\alpha \leq |X|$ is a non-empty cardinal, then there is a continuous map $f:X\to X$ such that $|f^{-1}(\{y\})| = \alpha$ for all $y\in X$.

Comment: If the continuum hypothesis CH is true, then the circle is such a space. If CH is not true, then the circle is not such a space (a closed subset of the circle is either countable or has cardinality the continuum, any cardinal in between cannot be realized as the preimage of a point).

Comment: Wow that's amazing @MathieuBaillif - thanks!

Comment: What is the proof for a circle when alpha is infinite?

Comment: For preimages of continuum cardinality, take the projection of a space (cylinder, rather) filling curve. For countable preimages, a function as in the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599921/countable-infinity-to-one-function/1600271#1600271